# coming out from this method

Tags: java

I have written code below ,and if this `else if` statement runs I want to come out from this method suddenly and back to the next of the line which this method was called.I have used return but it doesn't work well.

```
else if (balance == 0 && noSolution == 0) {
                noSolution = 0;
                return; // it doesn't work.
            }
```

METHOD:

```
    public <E> void rand_Function(List<E> tree, List<E> array) {

    if (array.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    if (array.size() == 1) {
        preorder = (List<Element>) new ArrayList<E>(tree);
        preorder.addAll((Collection<? extends Element>) array);
        for (Element e : preorder) {
            e.setLevel(0);
        }
        E1 = getAverageAccessTime(preorder);
        listTwo = new ArrayList<Element>(preorder);
        if ((E1 < E) || (rand.nextDouble() <= Math.exp(-(Math.abs(E1 - E)) / 0.5 * T))) {
            E = E1;
            listOne = listTwo;

        } else {
            noSolution++;
        }
        balance--;
        System.out.println("running"); // EDITED
        if (balance == 0 && noSolution ==1) {              
            noSolution = 0;
            T = 0.95 * T;           

        } else if (balance == 0 && noSolution == 0) {
            System.out.println("running");//EDITED
            noSolution = 0;
            return;//it doesn't work.
        }

    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            //create a list without the ith element
            List<E> newList = new ArrayList<E>(array);
            newList.remove(i);
            //create a list by adding the ith element to beginning
            List<E> newBeginning = new ArrayList<E>(tree);
            newBeginning.add(array.get(i));
            rand_Function(newBeginning, newList);
        }
    }

}
```

the function that method above was called :

```
  private void function(List<Element> list) {
        noSolution = 0;
        listOne = list;
        T = 5;
        balance = 3;
        E = getAverageAccessTime(listOne);
        for (Element e : listOne) {
            e.setLevel(0);
        }
        rand_Function(emptyList, listOne);
        System.out.println("coming out suddenly"); //I want to run this statement when I come out from the method above rand_Function(emptyList, listOne);suddenly!



    }
```

output which will return and I don't expect it :

```
run:
running
running
running
return
running
running
running
running
running
coming out suddenly
```

but I need this out put and I expect this one :

```
run:
running
running
running
return
coming out suddenly
```

Comment: I am confused.  If this is the complete code sample that function will return to the caller regardless of whether or not you call break return or nothing.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: also I have edited my post sorry :)

Comment: Given the shown code, a return statement won't matter, the function will return immediately anyway. The posted code is either not the real code, or there's something in the problem description that isn't communicated. Can you clarify what you mean with "come out suddenly"? Can you tell us what happens instead of what you expect?

Comment: Then what does it do when you step through a debugger? When it hits the line thats says return which line does it execute nexT?

Comment: I have edited my post and I put the output that I expect but it will print the not-expected output!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code sample uses `break;` not `return;` - break won't do the job.

Also, since you're recursing: `return` will not return more than one call level. If you want to exit all recursive calls immediately, you'll need to signal this to the caller.

E.g.

```
 public <E> boolean rand_Function(List<E> tree, List<E> array) {

    if (array.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    if (array.size() == 1) {
        preorder = (List<Element>) new ArrayList<E>(tree);
        preorder.addAll((Collection<? extends Element>) array);
        for (Element e : preorder) {
            e.setLevel(0);
        }
        E1 = getAverageAccessTime(preorder);
        listTwo = new ArrayList<Element>(preorder);
        if ((E1 < E) || (rand.nextDouble() <= Math.exp(-(Math.abs(E1 - E)) / 0.5 * T))) {
            E = E1;
            listOne = listTwo;

        } else {
            noSolution++;
        }
        balance--;
        System.out.println("running"); // EDITED
        if (balance == 0 && noSolution ==1) {              
            noSolution = 0;
            T = 0.95 * T;           

        } else if (balance == 0 && noSolution == 0) {
            System.out.println("running");//EDITED
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            //create a list without the ith element
            List<E> newList = new ArrayList<E>(array);
            newList.remove(i);
            //create a list by adding the ith element to beginning
            List<E> newBeginning = new ArrayList<E>(tree);
            newBeginning.add(array.get(i));
            if (!rand_Function(newBeginning, newList))
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: when I write "break" instead of "return" it will show this error that: break outside switch or loop!!!

Comment: The `return` statement works. Have you stepped through this code with a debugger to see what *really* happens?

Comment: sure!! it will go to the else if statement for coming out suddenly but it didn't and created the other remaining lists.

Comment: sorry but I couldn't get what you mean can you put these lines in my code?

Comment: yes ,now it works really it helps me !! thanks  a lot ,know I get what you mean :)

Answer (score 0):

As written, you are trying to use a `break` when not inside of a loop or a switch. `return` works correctly, as you are using it at the beginning when the list is empty.

You are also setting `noSolution` to 0 even though that block will only execute when it already equals 0.

In regards to your edit, you need to conventions when naming your variables. You have two variables that are single capital letters. This will make people think it is a generic type, especially when one of them is T. Also, since you are only giving us the method, we have to assume that all undefined variables are class variables, but could have ambiguous types or states.